# Custom formControlName in Angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How do I implement custom `formControlName` in Angular forms? I want to enable/disable check-boxes depending on some value in an array which is in a nested object.

Here's how the HTML looks.

```
           <span class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="userLookUpSource"
                   [(ngModel)]="systemUser"
                   [value]="1"
                   (change)="userLookUpSourceSourceChanged()" />
            <span>{{getMCText('SystemUser')}}</span>
          </span>
          <span class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="userLookUpSource"
                   [(ngModel)]="adUser"
                   [value]="2"
                   (change)="userLookUpSourceSourceChanged()" />
            <span>{{getMCText('ActiveDirectoryUser')}}</span>
          </span>
          <span class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="userLookUpSource"
                   [(ngModel)]="adGroup"
                   [value]="3"
                   (change)="userLookUpSourceSourceChanged()" />
            <span>{{getMCText('ActiveDirectoryGroup')}}</span>
          </span>
          <span class="col-md-2">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="userLookUpSource"
                   [(ngModel)]="applicationGroup"
                   [value]="4"
                   (change)="userLookUpSourceSourceChanged()" />
            <span>Application Security Group</span>
          </span>
```

Now on click of any checkbox of them, I want to enter its value in an array. Previously we used this. During the `ngmodelchange` method.

```
userLookUpSourceSourceChanged() {
    this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource = [];
    if (this.systemUser) {
      this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('1');
    }

    if (this.adUser) {
      this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('2');
    }

    if (this.adGroup) {
      this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('3');
    }

    if (this.applicationGroup) {
      this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('4');
    }
  }
```

Also, how do I get the same data back when I edit the form with an existing object. Can I do something `this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.includes('4')` and this enables the checkbox?

Comment: can you send the initialize statement for request please

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Wait. You're asking for help with Reactive Forms and `formControlName`, but supply code for Template-Driven Forms using `ngModel` instead. What do you actually want help for!?

Answer (score 0):

Create a typescript file "request.ts" with below code

```
export class Request {
  Properties: {
    userLookUpSource : any
  }
}
```

and insert the below initialize code in component class

```
request : Request = {Properties : [] };
```

check box change function

```
userLookUpSourceSourceChanged() : void {
        this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource = [];
        if (this.systemUser) {
            this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('1');
        }
        if (this.adUser) {
            this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('2');
        }

        if (this.adGroup) {
            this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('3');
        }

        if (this.applicationGroup) {
             this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource.push('4');
        }
        console.log(this.request.Properties.userLookUpSource)
    }
```

During editing we need to update below value as true based on previous selection

```
 systemUser = false;
 adUser = false;
 adGroup = true;
 applicationGroup = true;
```

Now last two checkbox will be checked.

Please let us know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks. But how does this thing work when I edit the form back? I need to read it back from the API as well. And it might come back like [2,4]

Comment: for [2,4] we need to assign aduser and applicationGroup to true